# Azure Chatbot - SSO with Webapp

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-bot-service

I have created a web application using Django and embedded the azure chatbot after publishing it. Once the user logs into the Web App, i would like to transmit login info to the chatbot embedded on the app in order to give customized interactions e.g. *"Hello Richard, How may i help you?"* etc.. I believe Azure AD SSO is a good option. But couldn't find good resources on how to implement it for my use case.

Is AAD SSO the best option?,

If yes, can anyone please guide me to resources that i can refer to implement it.

If no, please provide some info on what's the most optimal approach for this use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the samples for [Bot Authentication](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/18.bot-authentication) and [Bot Authentication with Azure and MSGraph](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph), as well as the [documentation on user auth in bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-use-oauth?tabs=v2x).

If your users can be authenticated using Azure AD SSO, then yes, it's a good solution.

Comment: Thank you for the response @AP01. As far as my understanding. I need to do the below steps:


1. Register my web app on Azure AD SSO and generate secret from there
2. Register my bot as per the above documentation page and use the secret from above to access here.
3. Once user logs onto my web app, as both my bot and web app are connected over SSO, bot will also be logged in


Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Correct, the bot will be authorized.